# Java blocking IO - Are there any advantages for write operations?

Tags: java, tcp, io, nio, nonblocking

In Java's blocking IO API `accept()` blocks until a connection is available and `read()` blocks until input is available.

But does `write()` block also for different blocking IO `OutputStreams`?
So how long does `write()` block in `FileOutputStream` and `SocketOutputStream` (TCP) classes?

Edit: or to ask even more generally: Does nonblocking IO have any advantages for write operations?

Comment: As long as it takes for the *payload* to be written.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch could you explain this for TCP and files in an answer? Do TCP outputstreams wait for the receiver to confirm the packet?

Comment: TCP and files are not the same thing. Why do you expect them to behave the same way? For the most part, the differences have been abstracted away; but I believe the actual underlying implementations are done in native code so it's a difficult thing to really answer.

Comment: A write to a socket will block when the buffer at the OS level is full and cannot accept any more data (for instance because it has trouble delivering that data to the other end). But that's all, really.

Comment: @fge Also for File IO? Doesn't the write block until the hard drive is done saving the file?

Comment: No -- that would be a huge performance loss! It is left to the OS to handle that stuff and it more often than not does a pretty nice job (also, modern filesystems are pretty fast and secure). You can however open a file in synchronous data mode, but that's only with java.nio.file (see `StandardOpenOption.SYNC` and `StandardOpenOption.DSYNC`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But does `write()` block also for different blocking IO `OutputStreams`? So how long does write() block in `FileOutputStream` and `SocketOutputStream` (TCP) classes?

It blocks until all data that you have asked to be written is delivered to the OS.  There is no theoretical upper bound on this.  There is no theoretical difference between the different kinds of stream classes.

In practice the length of time blocked depends on how fast the data can be delivered.  Writing to local files is generally fastest.  Anything involving networks depends on network (and NIC) bandwidth, latency and congestion.  (That includes cases where you are using file streams to read / write files to locally mounted remote file systems.)

---

> Does this mean that there is no performance improvement for blocking vs nonblocking writes? If there are such, what are they?

No it doesn't mean that ... exactly.  The *potential* performance improvement is not a direct one.

The performance improvement comes about if you have lots of connections that you are reading and / or writing.

- With blocking I/O, you effectively need one thread for each connection each thread has significant resources (e.g. thread stack memory) associated with it, and there are overheads whenever you make a thread context switch.  Having lots of threads *typically* also tends to increase other things, like lock contention, heap space usage, GC overheads, virtual memory footprint, paging activity.
- With non-blocking I/O (and selectors), you can use one thread to service multiple connections, either directly or by passing work off to worker threads via queues.

---

> Does nonblocking IO have any advantages for write operations?

Non-blocking I/O *when used correctly* allows you to support more simultaneous clients with less resources.  But for a single connection / client there is no speedup from using non-blocking I/O.

Comment: Does this mean that there is no performance improvement for blocking vs nonblocking writes? If there are such, what are they?

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock That is correct. There is no performance improvement. There is a potential *scalability* improvement, or at least that was the theory when NIO was introduced. Whether it's realized in practice is pretty moot, especially given some of the abstruse ways people have used NIO.

Comment: Could you provide some examples for potential write operation advantages?

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock - See my updated answer.  (No I can't provide you with examples, but I'm sure that Google can ... if you ask her politely)

Comment: Well I found this (hopefully I was politely enough): "Large writes over a slow socket, for example, can take a long time. In non-blocking mode, a call to write a large buffer over a slow socket would just queue up the data". What do they mean by "slow socket"? They can't mean it queues the data slowly right? Cause then nio wouldn't be an advantage either.

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock I do not understand why you are now asking about 'potential write operation advantages' when both this answer and my comment have already stated that there aren't any. I don't know where you got your quotation from but it is basically nonsense. All socket output has to be queued.

Comment: (I agree with EJP.  Nuff said.  I'm at work now ... supposed to be working.)